# Is there a place to find the MD5 or other checksum for Windows DLLs?

Tags: windows, security

I have a FIMS system that tells me that DLLs/EXEs have changed.  If those are Windows DLLs and we just did Windows update, I can assume they are not corrupted, but how do I know for sure?

Is there a location where I can get the correct checksum for a given Windows DLL / EXE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the System File Checker by using the command `sfc /scannow /verifyonly` (verifyonly is only availabale in 2008+).  See [Description of the Windows File Protection feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193) for more details.  Microsoft does have a [File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290) however I am unaware of any "default" list of checksums as that list would change depending on which hotfixes were applied, drivers, etc. (thus the creation of the SFC)